# Передача данных с RaspberryPi 3 на локальный сервер и удалённый сервер

Tags: клиент-сервер, raspberry-pi

Какой стэк технологий использовать для данной задачи?

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос. Какие технологии используете? Какая ОС на RaspberryPi? Что установлено на локальном и удалённом серверах? Какие средства разработки используете? В чем конкретно видите проблему?

Comment: На RaspberryPi стоит Raspbian. На RaspberryPi с помощью Python 3.6.3  собираю JSON с данными используя подключенный модуль json и для передачи данных  urllib.request. На локальном сервере поднял Apache, на котором прием данных и запись их в MySQL пытаюсь организовать с помощью PHP.  Использую Python Shell 3.6.3 и Sublime Text. Общая картина идеи - RaspberryPi передает и принимает данные и команды с сервера на который команды будет отправлять клиент (с web-app, или с android-app). Проблема что из-за малого опыта, сомнения в том, стоит использовать для данной задачи на сервере PHP?

Comment: Если вы плохо владеете PHP, то можете на сервере использовать тот же Python